# Reading a directory from a JSON file in Python

Tags: json, python-3.x

Trying to read data from a JSON file that contains a directory but unfortunately the directory has escape characters in it.

see below my code and JSON file.

config.json

```
{
    "src": "C:\Users\tom",
    "dst": "output"
}
```

run.py

```
import os
import json

# Set config
with open('config.json') as json_data_file:
    data = json.load(json_data_file)
    src = data["src"]
    dst = data["dst"]
```

The error that I am receiving follows:

> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 11 (char 15)

I have re-written the code for this question so the values above are incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

JSON requires you to escape backslashes, so simply replace every `\` with `\\` in `config.json`.

Answer (score 0):

I would replace single backslashes with double before parsing and then replace the double back to single:

import json

```
with open('config.json') as fileobj:
    raw = fileobj.read().replace('\\', '\\\\')
    data = json.loads(raw)
    src = data['src'].replace('\\\\', '\\')
    dst = data['dst'].replace('\\\\', '\\')
    print(src)
    print(dst)
```